# Mariadb 5.5 slower than MySQL 5.1

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a query that runs in about 20 seconds on a MySQL 5.1 server but takes almost 15 minutes on a MariaDB 5.5 server.
Usual suspects like key_buffer_size and tmp_table_size and max_heap_table_size are all equal (128M). Most settings are equal as far as I can see (query_cache,etc)

The query:

```
SELECT  products.id, 
concat(publications.company_name,' [',publications.quote,'] ', products.name) as n, 
products.impressions, 
products.contacts, 
is_channel, 
sl.i, 
count(*) 
FROM products 
LEFT JOIN publications ON products.publications_id = publications.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (  
    SELECT adspace.id AS i, 
    slots.products_id FROM adspace 
    LEFT JOIN  slots ON adspace.slots_id = slots.id 
        AND adspace.end > '2016-01-25 10:28:49' 
        WHERE adspace.active = 1) AS sl 
    ON sl.products_id = products.id  
WHERE 1 = 1 
AND publications.active=1 
GROUP BY products.id 
ORDER BY n ASC;
```

The only difference is in the explain fase:

Old server (MySQL 5.1)

```
+----+-------------+--------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------------------------------------+--------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table        | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref                                     | rows   | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+--------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------------------------------------+--------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | products     | ALL    | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                                    |   6568 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | publications | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | db.products.publications_id |      1 | Using where                                 |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2>   | ALL    | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                                    |  94478 |                                 |
|  2 | DERIVED     | adspace      | ALL    | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                                    | 101454 | Using where                     |
|  2 | DERIVED     | slots        | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | db.adspace.slots_id         |      1 |                                             |
+----+-------------+--------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------------------------------------+--------+---------------------------------+
```

New server (MariaDB 5.5)

```
+------+-------------+--------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------------------------------------+--------+---------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table        | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref                                     | rows   | Extra                           |
+------+-------------+--------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------------------------------------+--------+---------------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | products     | ALL    | test_idx      | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                                    |   6557 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | publications | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | db.products.publications_id |      1 | Using where                                 |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | adspace      | ALL    | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                                    | 100938 | Using where                     |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | slots        | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | db.adspace.slots_id         |      1 | Using where                                 |
+------+-------------+--------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------------------------------------+--------+---------------------------------+
```

An index was added to the products table on the new server to speed things up, to no avail.

Engine variables:

Old server:

```
mysql> show variables like '%engine%';
+---------------------------+--------+
| Variable_name             | Value  |
+---------------------------+--------+
| engine_condition_pushdown | ON     |
| storage_engine            | MyISAM |
+---------------------------+--------+

mysql> show variables like '%buffer_pool%';
+-------------------------+---------+
| Variable_name           | Value   |
+-------------------------+---------+
| innodb_buffer_pool_size | 8388608 |
+-------------------------+---------+
```

New server:

```
MariaDB [db]> show variables like '%engine%';
+---------------------------+--------+
| Variable_name             | Value  |
+---------------------------+--------+
| default_storage_engine    | InnoDB |
| engine_condition_pushdown | OFF    |
| storage_engine            | InnoDB |
+---------------------------+--------+


MariaDB [db]> show variables like '%buffer_pool%';
+---------------------------------------+-----------+
| Variable_name                         | Value     |
+---------------------------------------+-----------+
| innodb_blocking_buffer_pool_restore   | OFF       |
| innodb_buffer_pool_instances          | 1         |
| innodb_buffer_pool_populate           | OFF       |
| innodb_buffer_pool_restore_at_startup | 0         |
| innodb_buffer_pool_shm_checksum       | ON        |
| innodb_buffer_pool_shm_key            | 0         |
| innodb_buffer_pool_size               | 134217728 |
+---------------------------------------+-----------+
```

All tables used in the query are MyISAM (both old and new server)

Profiling showed that the old query spend around 16 seconds in 'copying to tmp table' and the new server around 800 seconds in this fase.

New server all has SSD disks for storage and old servers have normal disks.

**Edit**: I also have a MySQL 5.5 server and there the query only take around 10 seconds. Also with all the same settings as far as I can see.

I tried to summarise it in a table:

```
Location:       Customer                    Own                     Customer
MySQL Type:     MySQL                       MySQL                   MariaDB
Mysql Version:  5.1.56-community-log        5.5.39-1-log (Debian)   5.5.44-MariaDB-log
HDD:            Normal                      Normal                  SSD
Type:           Virtual                     Real                    Virtual
Query time:     ~15s                        ~10s                    ~15min
DB engine:      MyISAM                      InnoDB                  InnoDB
Table Engine:   MyISAM                      MyISAM                  MyISAM
```

I don't want to rewrite the query (although it could use some work) but I want to find the difference between the 2 machines, my guess is a setting that isn't ideal in MariaDB but I can't find it.

Comment: Are you sure you use the same table engine for both databases?

Comment: Perhaps that answers your question: Completely different storage engine...

Comment: So if I understand you correct, the engine on database level will make the difference even if the engine on table level is the same?

Comment: Edit: I also have a server with MySQL 5.5 available and there it only takes 8 seconds. So it should be something MariaDB related. Since Mysql 5.5 also has default engine=InnoDB and storage engine=InnoDB.

Comment: For the new server, what does `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%buffer_pool%';` say? Basically, InnoDB is "tuned" to work with low-RAM settings by default. How much RAM does the new server have, how much did you allocate to InnoDB and how much data is in your DB to begin with? The reason for different performance levels is that InnoDB apparently can't use sufficient memory for I/O so it's reading from the disk - and in your case, you have a terribly slow disk since it takes that long to scan below 1m records.

Comment: See edited opening post, new server has SSD, old server has normal disks. New server should be running circles around the old one.

Comment: It should, that's true. How come you have such a low buffer pool for the new server? It should be increased do match the size of your data. It's quite odd that an SSD would be this slow, which brings up the issue of the controller in the server. Is this a physical server or virtual one, cloud based?

Comment: AFAIK a virtual one, we don't have access to it, since it's our client that set up the machine. And the low buffer pool was copied from the old one where we didn't have this performance issue. Granted it could use a boost, but for now I want to keep settings the same as much as possible to find the culprit. Thanks for the tips though.

Comment: Well, the old system you had was MyISAM and buffer_pool doesn't apply to it.. and if there are virtual SSDs then the I/O and bandwith rate can be lower than an actual physical disk can achieve. I think you determined 100% accurately that the new server has worse HDD subsystem. However, since it's InnoDB that you're using, there is no reason to avoid upping the buffer pool so that the DB can really perform well. Anyway, good luck, I think you have the required information to make a decision.

Comment: Thanks for all the info @Mjh, really appreciate it.

Comment: No problem at all, good luck with fixing the issue!

Comment: I have a theory about the speed diff in the versions, but first a request...  Would the query get the same answer if all the `LEFTs` were removed?  Would the `EXPLAINs` change if the `LEFTs` were removed?

Comment: (I am getting lost on all the addenda.)  Could you build a little summary table of the results -- MySQL/MariaDB, version, HDD/SSD, seconds, MyISAM/InnoDB.

Comment: @Rick James: I added a summary table. Hope it has enough info.

Comment: Thanks, the table makes it clearer.  Is "DB engine" the "default engine"?  (If so, that is probably not relevant.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the explanation above can be seen that the [Derived Table Merge Optimization](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/derived-table-merge-optimization/) is used. That unfortunately in your case means that instead of only one full table scan over `adspace`some ~6k are done.

A possible solution is to disable the optimization before the query by issuing `set optimizer_switch='derived_merge=off';`. A backward compatible alternatively would be adding `GROUP BY adspace.id, slots.products_id` to the subquery (if it does not change the results - safest is grouping over PKs of all joined tables) which forbids the merge by having different semantics.

There is one reported [optimizer bug](https://mariadb.atlassian.net/browse/MDEV-7946) about that - your case might help with it.

Comment: The setting of derived_merge=OFF made the query go from ~15min to ~0.3seconds. Small speed increase :)

Comment: @darkownage - I am confused by your comment -- was it a significant _decrease_? or an _increase_?

Comment: @RickJames - Sorry for the weird sentence :) The query went from about 15min to 0,5 seconds. So the speed increase was huge. We opted for turning this 'optimization' off because it was blocking and the query did it's job and was the easiest fix. Hope this answers your question :)

Comment: @jkavalik you saved my life. Spent an entire day trying to figure out settings why a query that was taking 0.9 seconds on the old MySQL database server was taking 4.5 minutes on the MariaDB server. Turning off the 'derived_merge' flag decreased the time for the MariaDB query to 0.8 seconds. What a difference! I don't understand why this flag is defaulted to ON if the performance hit is so great. Or at least MariaDB should document it better for users switching from MySQL.

Comment: @Johnny it is only slower for quite specific cases. It helps a lot with other queries. The only problem is that the optimizer is not able to identify the problematic cases automatically and that is probably quite hard problem.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the answer but MariaDB 5.5 uses a different algorithm to perform a join. As far as i know in MariaDB 5.5 [Batch Key Access Join](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/block-based-join-algorithms/#batch-key-access-join) was introduced. Older Versions of MySQL or MariaDB use a different one.
Although the new version should be faster in most cases, maybe your specific tables performed better using the old one.

Edit: This answer might be obsolote as you mentioned that you used different storage engines.